# Using multiple foreign keys in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have these tables

**Client**

```
id(PK), name, logo
```

**School**

```
id(PK), name, logo, client_id (FK)
```

**Class**

```
id(PK), name, school_id (FK)
```

**Subject**

```
id(PK), name, class_id (FK)
```

Approach 1.

I have subject id, I need to get class_id, school_id and client_id of the subject. I can write a query with JOIN to fetch the ids from Client, School, Class tables

Approach 2

I have the table design like this

**Client**

```
id(PK), name, logo
```

**School**

```
id(PK), name, logo, client_id (FK)
```

**Class**

```
id(PK), name, school_id (FK), client_id (FK)
```

**Subject**

```
id(PK), name, class_id (FK), class_id (FK), school_id (FK), client_id (FK)
```

In this case I can get all the details by a simple query like

```
SELECT * FROM Subject WHERE id = '2'
```

Which one is the better and recommended approach? I like the 2nd approach but not sure if its recommended.

TIA

Comment: Why does school have `client_id` as FK? What are you trying to say by this relation?

Comment: @Vyktor Each school is associated to a client. A client can have multiple Schools.

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise the second approach is beter at SELECT. It all depends how much you will need the ids. It's the same in programming structures. Do I need a pointer to parent most structure or not? It depends on the types of operations that we will have. The tradeoff is space and sinhronization, which in most cases isn't the problem because primary key is unique identifier.

I would mix it. I wouldn't put all the foreign keys like you did. Does the Class table need a client_id? In your case I would live foreign keys in Subject, but if performance is not an issue I would use joins.

Also to note school_id and client_id in table Subject are foreign keys.